# Why does the Rails "new" action have an XML format directive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newcomer to Rails, and have been following the tutorial on the [rails webpage](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
Using the scaffold instruction to create a "post" model, I found that the `new` action in the controller has a special directive for XML format:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
  end
end
```

I can't see the reasoning for supporting an XML request when creating a new post. Browsing to /posts/new.xml returns nothing. What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning for it behind the `new` action is simply to provide a xml client with the default data (or something else if you want).

The format directive is being used by all routes, and you don't need to support a format unless you want to.

The above code could might as well have looked like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # renders new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => {:message => "XML is not supported"} }
  format.json { render :text => @post.to_json }
  format.js # renders new.js.erb
end
```

Also, this is not limited to the `new` action, but is available in all your actions. The format to use is either taken from the url (if the route is set up to use it), or from the HTTP-Accept header that the browser sends.